# Lighthouse asks me to defer loading of /

Tags: html, css, performance, performance-testing, lighthouse

I have deferred my stylesheets to the bottom of the page, with some initial css inlined at the top, but still get a low score on lighthouse. When i check the pointers, it only suggests deferring loading for / (see image)

[image]

Can anyone make sense of this for me?

Answer (score 0):

The "/" means you have inline styles on the page.
The size just shows an overall page size client needs to download(html and inline css).

The only way to get rid of it is to reduce your page size.

Hope it helps.
Pav